# ¿Porqué me marca source: no such file or directory?

Tags: macos

Estoy tratando de ejecutar el siguiente comando pero obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

```
ivancaballerocano@Mac-mini-de-Ivan bdRespaldo % source ~/.profile
```

source: no such file or directory: /Users/ivancaballerocano/.profile

No soy experto para nada en comandos de UNIX, estoy usando una MAC y no sé por que indica eso

Comment: Y si ejecutas `ls -al ~`, ves el archivo .profile?

Comment: no no se ve-......  :O

Comment: Entonces no existe y el OS dice la verdad. Posiblemente estés interesado en cargar variables de entorno o algo así... significa que editaste el archivo equivocado / no guardaste / no tenías permisos

Comment: Todo esto es porque trato de ejecutar un comando cron con un crontab que tiene uno comando simple para respaldar una bd MYSQL pero no parece ejecutarse y estoy tratando de agregar la ruta del comando al $PATH.... pero no se mucho de eso y por ahí leí que este comando sirve como para eso....la verdad ni sé, no entiendo mucho de UNIX

Comment: Creo que bien podrías editar la pregunta y, más bien, poner lo que has intentado para ejecutar tu cron y el resultado esperado. Editar también el título y las etiquetas. Esta pregunta, como pudimos probar, no se puede reproducir y seguro termina cerrada :)

Comment: Ok la editaré bien